# Number of path connected components

Tags: general-topology, geometric-group-theory

Is it possible to give an explicit characterization of compact subsets of $[0,\infty)$. Is it true that given any compact subset $K \subseteq [0,\infty)$ then $[0,\infty) \setminus K$ has only one path connected component? Why?

I'm trying to show formally that $[0,\infty)$ has only one end, so we take a compact subset $C$ of $[0,\infty)$ and let $r: [0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a continuous map. Then there must exist $L>0$ such that $r([L,\infty))$ is contained in some component of $[0,\infty) \setminus C$.

Why there is only one equivalence class though? it seems to me that the complement of a compact set in $[0,\infty)$ has two connected path components.

From page $6$ of http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.3771.pdf

**Definition** A proper ray is a map $[0,\infty) \rightarrow X$ such that the preimage of a compact set is compact again. Two proper rays $c_{0},c_{1}: [0,\infty) \rightarrow X$ converge to the same end if for every compact subset $C \subseteq X$ there is $R>0$ such that $c_{0}([R,\infty))$ and $c_{1}([R,\infty))$ lie in the same component of $X \setminus C$. This defines an equivalence relation on the set of proper rays. The set of equivalence classes is the set of ends. The number of ends of $X$ is the cardinality of this set.

Comment: Only one path connected component? Certainly not. What if $K$ is the point $1$?

Comment: vdoes "closed and bounded" sound explicit enough? The Cantor set is compact and its complement has countably infinitely many path components. What is your definition of an end? I don't understand what you are after even though you added details.

Comment: @Mirko: thanks for your interest; I've added the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any compact subset $S$ of $[0,\infty)$ is contained in an interval $[0,x]$ for some $x$.  Then $r^{-1}([0,x])$ is compact so it fails to intersect $[L,\infty)$ for some $L$.  Thus, $r([L,\infty)) \subset (x,\infty) \subset [0,\infty) \setminus S$.

So, given two proper rays $c_0, c_1$ and some compact $C \subset [0,\infty)$, we have by the above argument $L_0, L_1$ s.t. $c_0([L_0,\infty)$ and $c_1([L_1,\infty))$ lie in the same component of $[0,\infty) \setminus C$.  Let $R = \max(L_0,L_1)$.

Comment: Intersect, thanks.

Comment: just to make sure I'm following, your argument shows that given two rays $r,s$ we can always find $L$ large enough such that $r([L,\infty))$ and $s([L,\infty))$ are both contained in the connected component $(x,\infty)$ of $[0,\infty) \setminus S$. Thus any two rays are identified so there is only one equivalence class. Is that right? thanks!

Comment: Well really I was just doing part of the argument, let me finish it for you.

Comment: yeah I thought that, thanks for such a complete answer.